# sql query for hotel data base

Tags: sql

I am attempting to answer the following question from a hotel database

Show the number of bookings, for each month of the 2011 calendar year.

This is what I have come up with so far.

```
SELECT booking_no,
       date_in,
       Count(*)
FROM   booking
WHERE  date_in >= '01-jan-11'
       AND date_in <= '31-dec-11'
GROUP  BY booking_no,
          date_in
ORDER  BY date_in;
```

These are the database headings

GUEST

```
Name Type
--------------------- ------------
GUEST_NO 
SURNAME 
GIVEN 
DOB 
SEX 
HOME_PHONE 
WORK_PHONE 
FAX 
ADDRESS 
SUBURB 
STATE 
POSTCODE
```

ROOM

```
Name Type
--------------------- ------------
ROOM_NO 
FLOOR_NO 
SPA_BATH 
NUM_BEDS 
PRICE 
LINKED_ROOM_NO )
```

BOOKING

```
Name Type
--------------------- -----------
BOOKING_NO 
GUEST_NO 
ROOM_NO
DATE_IN 
DATE_OUT
```

Comment: Ypu seem to be wanting a grouping by MONTH not date.

Answer (score 1):

You want the number per month, so

```
select month(date_in), count(*) 
from booking 
where year(date_in)=2011
group by month(date_in)
order by month(date_in);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try his:

```
SELECT Count(booking_no) bookings,
       Month(date_in)    month_name
FROM   booking
WHERE  date_in >= '01-jan-11'
       AND date_in <= '31-dec-11'
GROUP  BY Month(date_in)
ORDER  BY Month(date_in);
```

Don't do  "`year(date_in)=2011`" in the where clause, it will prevent the usage of an index, if you have one on the `date_in` column. If you don't have one, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `MONTH` function. This is the same in most database engines. So try

```
SELECT booking_no, Month(date_in), Count(booking_no)
```

and

```
GROUP BY Month(date_in)
ORDER BY Month(date_in);
```

You could also simplify your where clause with the `YEAR`:

```
WHERE Year(date_in) = 2011
```

Altogether:

```
SELECT Month(date_in),
       Count(*)
FROM   booking
WHERE  Year(date_in) = 2011
GROUP  BY Month(date_in)
ORDER  BY Month(date_in);
```